# Spring boot exception for a very simple app

Tags: java, exception, spring-boot

My application has this. It has not hibernate or jpa stuff it yet. I added only in libraries in pom.xml:

```
    @SpringBootApplication
    @ComponentScan("com.ma.vegshopping")
    public class VegShoppingApplication {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(VegShoppingApplication.class, args);
        }
    }
```

pom.xml:

```
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
            <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
                <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

                <groupId>com.ma</groupId>
                <artifactId>VegShopping</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
                <packaging>jar</packaging>

                <name>VegShopping</name>
                <description>vegetable shopping list</description>

                <parent>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
                    <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
                    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
                </parent>

                <properties>
                    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
                    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
                    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
                </properties>

                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-social-facebook</artifactId>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
                    </dependency>

                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                        <scope>runtime</scope>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                        <scope>test</scope>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>

                <build>
                    <plugins>
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        </plugin>
                    </plugins>
                </build>


            </project>
```

When try to start app, I get following exception:

> ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Tomcat.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to active it (no profiles are currently active).

Comment: Well, if you don't want to have JPA, don't add spring-boot-starter-data-jpa to your dependencies. As the exception shows, adding it activates auto-configuration looking for a datasource, because when using JPA, you need a datasource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When u put the JPA hibernate jars are brought into classpath. And when Hibernate is available in classpath Spring Boot AutoConfiguration is picked for Creating the EntityManager.

This is the default behaviour of Spring boot.
Since you dont have any datasource for Hibernate the startup is failing.

Try creating a datasource by giving properties in your application.properties / yml file. 
If u dont want to use hibernate or jpa then remove jpa starter from your pom.xml